# Восстановление доступа к joomla сайту 1.5.22

Tags: joomla, php

Сайт под управлением Joomla 1.5.22 подвергся атаке вирусов, после чего перестала работать авторизация в админку сайта. При попытке авторизации выдаёт сообщение "У вас нет доступа к административной панели сайта." , покопался в интернете - говорят плагины авторизации и плагины пользователя не работают, всё проверил, включил - не пускает. Проверил принадлежность пользователя к группе Super Administrators - есть. Проверил сами группы в таблице jos_core_acl_aro_groups всё на месте, на всякий случай пересоздал из инсталятора joomla такой же версии - не помогло. Заменил файлы компонента administrator/componets/com_login - не помогло. Подскажите, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, ума не приложу что делать. Заранее спасибо!

-30 01 2013 - новые подробности
В общем методом проб и ошибок я кое как запустил сайт. Точнее перенёс. Я установил joomla 1.5.22 на отдельном поддомене и начал перетаскивать частями БД и файлы сайта. Практически всё заработало, однако при заходе в админку стало выдавать просто белый экран. Покопался в интернете подсказали добавить в administrator/ файл .htaccess и указать в нём настройку для отображения ошибок php. Так и сделал, в результате увидел кучу ошибок такого плана:

**Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in.  путь до файла...**

все ошибки ссылаются в папку libraries/ в корне сайта. Пробовал выключать отображение ошибок (как советовали на форумах), оставлять только предупреждения - не помогло. Причём меня авторизует в админпанели, если я введу адрес, например: /index.php?option=com_content - то попаду как авторизованный администратор в "Менеджер материалов" сайта. Так же я буду нормально работать если не заходить на /index.php . Что это может такое быть? В интернете пишут, что может из-за ПО на сервере, другие пишут из-за версии php и т.п. Пробовал сайт на 2-х разных хостингах с php 5.2 и на localhost с php 5.3 - ничего не помогает! ((( Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и решил её - поделитесь опытом пожалуйста. ))) Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается очень просто: заходишь в `phpMyAdmin` и в таблице `префикс_users` там админу `username`
меняешь и пароль новый пишешь, потом выбери в функциях `MD5`, сохраняй и всё готово, спокойно заходи!

P.S. maler1988 легких путей явно не ищешь )